# how to display other information after hitting the button?

Tags: html, coldfusion

My intention is: first I want to display a button on the page, after hitting the button, the button will be removed and display some other information. Thus I used the following code, but it doesn't work, the button is still there and "other information" doesn't show either. Can you guys provide some suggestions where I went wrong here? Thanks in advance.

This is the code to display information:

```
    <cfif displayMessage eq 1>
        <cfif ifUploaded eq 0>
            <div id='message_box'>
            <cffile action="upload" filefield="PRESENTATION_FILENAME" destination="#ExpandPath("./uploads/")#" nameconflict="overwrite">
            <cfset myfile = #cffile.clientFile#>
            <cfset myurl = mid(cgi.HTTP_REFERER,1,46) & 'uploads/' & #myfile#>
            <div id="btn"><input type="button" name="kalturaBtn" value="upload to kaltura" href="javascript:void();" onclick="popupwindow('https://lampa.human.cornell.edu/csg.kaltura/test.php?kurl=#myurl#&kname=#form.title#&rec=#ddl_choice#','','1200', '700'); return false;"></div>
           </div>
        </cfif>
     </cfif>

    <cfif ifUploaded eq 1>
        <div id='message_box'>
        <div>#messageTitle#</div>
        <div>#messageBody#</div>
    </cfif>
```

and I have following code to set the "displayMessage" and "ifUploaded" to display different information after hitting the "kalturaBtn" button.

```
<cfif kalturaBtn eq "upload to kaltura"> 
    <cfset ifUploaded = "1">
    <cfset displayMessage = "0">
</cfif>
```

The reason that why I used another variable "displayMessage" here is: all those information will only be displayed after I submitting a form on this page.

HTML Code:

```
     <cfoutput>
        <cfform name="frmPresentation" id="frmPresentation" action="#CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <!--- Information Table --->
        <div id='main_body'>
            <div id='inside'>
            <div style='text-align: center; font: bold 18pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-'serif'>CHE Multimedia Management Page</div>
                <br/>
                <cfif displayMessage eq 1 AND len(form.PRESENTATION_FILENAME) gt 0>
                    <cfif ifUploaded eq 0>
                    <div id='message_box'>
                        <cffile action="upload" filefield="PRESENTATION_FILENAME" destination="#ExpandPath("./uploads/")#" nameconflict="overwrite">
                        <cfset myfile = #cffile.clientFile#>
                        <cfset myurl = mid(cgi.HTTP_REFERER,1,46) & 'uploads/' & #myfile#>
                        <div id="btn"><input type="button" name="kalturaBtn" value="upload to kaltura" href="javascript:void();" onclick="popupwindow('https://lampa.human.cornell.edu/csg.kaltura/test.php?kurl=#myurl#&kname=#form.title#&rec=#ddl_choice#','','1200', '700'); return false;"></div>
                        <span onclick='this.parentNode.style.display="none"'></span>
                       </div>
                    </cfif>
                 </cfif>

                    <cfif ifUploaded eq 1>
                        <div id='message_box'>
                        <div>#messageTitle#</div>
                        <div>#messageBody#</div>
                        </div>
                    </cfif>

                   <cfdump var="#kalturaBtn#">

     // a lot of other code omitted here
     <input type='submit' name='submitMedia' value='Submit Changes' class='submit' onclick='return confirmSubmit()'/>
    </form>
    </cfoutput>
```

Comment: output each value to the screen to make sure you're getting the values you want. As an aside I'd recommend using true/false instead of 1/0 for clarity.

Comment: @MattBusche I used the <cfdump> to output some variables, it seems that the <cfif kalturaBtn eq "upload to kaltura"> code was not executed.

Comment: The code more or less looks okay. If the code to set `ifUploaded` and `displayMessage` is not processing then the problem is client side. One minor suggestion is to always scope your variables. If this is a form variable then use `<cfif form.kalturaBtn....>`. Sometimes, however not likely here, CF is using a different variable than the one you think it is, when you use unscoped variables. It also can lead to security problems. Does `kalturaBtn` show up in your `cfdump`, what is the value?

Comment: @cfqueryparam Thanks for your suggestion. After hitting the button, the `kalturaBtn` is still empty string.

Comment: @KevinZhu You'll have to post your html code but it sounds like something is wrong with your html form.

Comment: Hi @cfqueryparam, I have pasted my html code, basically the entire page is a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, maybe this will help you.

You're trying to use a plain button to submit the form.

```
<input type="button" name="kalturaBtn" value="upload to kaltura" href="javascript:void();" onclick="popupwindow('https://lampa.human.cornell.edu/csg.kaltura/test.php?kurl=#myurl#&kname=#form.title#&rec=#ddl_choice#','','1200', '700'); return false;">`
```

Instead, you need to use a submit button. The other thing causing a problem for you is that after the `popupwindow()` script, you have `return false` which is canceling the form submission. Change both of these things like so and your form should work. Also, input elements don't have href attributes.

```
<input type="submit" name="kalturaBtn" value="upload to kaltura" onclick="popupwindow('https://lampa.human.cornell.edu/csg.kaltura/test.php?kurl=#myurl#&kname=#form.title#&rec=#ddl_choice#','','1200', '700')">`
```

Your page wasn't changing because your form wasn't submitting.

Comment: problem solved! what a stupid mistake, thanks so much